# Playing videos inside a Node Webkit <webview>?

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app, node-webkit

I'm working on a Node Webkit project (now called NW.js). The latest stable version of NW (0.12.1) allows the "webview" tag from Chrome extensions to be integrated into a NW project.

After some initial testing, the webview tag seems to work fine for displaying basic webpages. But it won't display any Flash videos embedded in a webpage.

Flash videos play just fine outside of webview (ie in the normal NW browser), as I have "plugin" set to "true" in package.json, thereby using the Flash dll installed on my system. They just don't play *inside* a webview.

I just came across an article here...

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#local_resources

...which states that "webviews are prevented from loading any resources packaged with the app". So I'm guessing maybe that is what's preventing any Flash dll's installed on my system from being used by webview? I'm not quite sure how to fix this though (assuming this is even the actual problem). Do I need to create a manifest.json file specifically for this, as stated in the article linked to above? If so, what exactly would I put in there? I've been using NW for a while, but haven't really messed around with Chrome extensions code at all, so that part's still a bit fuzzy to me.

Thanks!

Comment: Well.. Chrome Apps have Flash [expressly banned](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated), but I can't say how it applies to NW.js

Comment: Hmmm... didn't realize that. I just did some more testing though, and I can't even get HTML5 videos to play inside webview (ie... http://html5demos.com/video). I'm sure there's a simple setting somewhere or permission that I need to allow for this to work, but no clue what I need to do here.

Comment: Looks like a _very_ niche question, I guess only NW.js people can answer. Did you also ask in the issues part of the GitHub project?

Comment: No... I'm not sure if it's an actual "issue", or just something that was never implemented in the first place. I did post the question to the NW Google groups before coming here, but no reply yet... not much activity over there, unfortunately. Ashame, as it's such a great platform. Thx anyways.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?